# Possible to automate updating development database on a VM?

Tags: mysql, automation

Using MySQL 5.6 and VM Workstation Pro 12.1.1.

At my job, the way things are set up is that my development environment is a locally hosted Virtual Machine.  Every day the first thing I need to do is to export a copy of the current database, bring it over to the VM, then import it on the VM's MySQL Server.  It takes about 15 minutes every day, not to mention sometimes I will get a ticket about a newly created item that was created after I updated the dev MySQL in the morning and I have to repeat the process.

Is there a way to bundle these actions in a script I can just have called automatically at say 6 am before I come into work?  And then again whenever need be?

To make things easier/harder, I know our database takes backups at midnight every night and the exact location/file name it will be, its on a network drive that requires a password however.

Comment: What if it were a Slave?  That way, all changes would be 'instantly' copied to the dev db.

Comment: The VM as a slave?  I've heard the term before in CS but I am not completely familiar with it.  Got a link or something I can google?

Comment: "MySQL replication"

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I am looking for.